# calculating ${Q + K - 1 \choose K - 1}$ *$k!$. with logic,K*product(K-i+Q) , for i=1..(K-1)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I need to calculate ${Q + K - 1 \choose K - 1}$ *$k!$.
I came across this small logic which calculates the above expression but could not get the logic as how this works ?

Here is the logic :

K*product(K-i+Q)   , for i=1..(K-1)

and here is the code that i got

```
                long r = K;
                for (int i=1; i<=K-1; i++) {
                    r = ( r * ((K - i + Q);
                }
```

I need an explanation as how the logic is correct ?

Comment: You may want to properly format your posts with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

That snippet of code calculates

$$K\prod_{i=1}^{K-1}(K-i+Q)\;.$$

As $i$ runs from $1$ to $K-1$, the factor $K-i+Q$ runs from $K-1+Q$ down to $1+Q$, so

$$\prod_{i=1}^{K-1}(K-i+Q)=(K-1+Q)(K-2+Q)\ldots(1+Q)=\frac{(K-1+Q)!}{Q!}\;.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
K\prod_{i=1}^{K-1}(K-i+Q)&=K\cdot\frac{(K-1+Q)!}{Q!}\\
&=K(K-1)!\cdot\frac{(K-1+Q)!}{Q!(K-1)!}\\
&=K!\binom{K-1+Q}{K-1}\;.
\end{align*}$$